# Visual studio Coded UI test, how to make tests run with different setup/cleanup scripts in the same test project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, coded-ui-tests

how to run coded ui tests with different setup/cleanup scripts? 
For example I have 8 coded ui tests in my test project and few setup/cleanup scripts. 
When run this test suite (all 8 tests in sequence automaticly), it is possible just to select on one active setup/cleanup script (which I added in test menu). What if i need 8 different setup/cleanup scripts? Is the only way to run tests one by one and every time select different setup/cleanup script?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in feature to select different setup/cleanup functions from the test menu. Assuming the test setup/cleanup scripts are different depending on the testing scenario, you could use a dialog box or create an ordered test for each combination of setup/cleanup tests you want to run.

I would probably lean toward using a modal dialog box or Form in the class/assembly initialize methods and a test settings class/struct that could be used to check the correct test initialize function for each test run.

Comment: So you say that i should create [TestInitialize] and cleanup methods for each test separately? Just write it down in the code? Sorry, my english is a little bit bad in technical discussions

Comment: You could do that, but you would need to break your test methods into separate classes as TestInitialize will act on every test method in the class.

Comment: My suggestion would be to have one testinitialize/cleanup method and switch the version used based on a dialog in a classinitialize method